# Spark very slow performance when processing big input

Tags: performance, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am using Spark (in Scala) to read a file containing a list of users and pages they shared, and I want to find all users at a certain distance of separation from a given user by the pages they shared in common.

The program is performing very badly, and often I get `GC overhead limit exceeded` errors.

I am running Spark locally on Mac OSX with 8 GB of ram. Program is submitted using `spark-submit` with arguments `--driver-memory 5g` and 8 cores assigned by setting `spark.cores.max`. The input set is a file of 1.15 GB.

Does anyone have an indication which operation is very inefficient, and if there is a better alternative for that operation?

Thanks in advance.

The code is briefly described here.

Each user entry contains the pages he/she shared after a tab, and each entry is separated by two linebreaks like so:

```
John Doe    <tab>    Page 1
            <tab>    Page 2
            <tab>    Page 3

User 2      <tab>    ...
```

First I read the input file using `newAPIHadoopFile`.

```
val hdpConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
hdpConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n\n")
val hadoopFile = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("user_pages.list", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], hdpConf)
```

Now I turn this into pairs `(user, Array(pagesShared))` like so

```
val pagesPerUser = hadoopFile.map {
    line =>
        val line_splitted = line._2.toString.split("\t");
        (line_splitted(0), line_splitted.drop(1).mkString.split("\n"))
}
```

Then I create an RDD containing single `(k,v)` pairs for every user and page combination `(page, user)`.

```
val pageAndUser = pagesPerUser.flatMap(line => line._2.map(page => (line._1, page)))
    .map(...)
    .filter(...)
```

The `map` uses `replaceAll` to filter the page title, and `filter` removes any entries containing certain titles that contain quotation marks and a regex using `matches()` to check if the title fulfills some more criteria.

Then I create pairs of every user directly linked to another user `(user, user)` which is then converted to an RDD of the form `(user, Array(user))` (containing all directly connected users by same page shared).

```
val pageAndUsers = pageAndUser.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toArray)
    .map(line => line._2)
val commonUsers = pageAndUsers.flatMap(users => users.map(user => (user, users)))
    .reduceByKey(_ ++ _).cache()
    .map(users => (users._1, users._2.distinct))
```

This RDD can then be used to determine the distances between users more further, but I think the slow performance is mainly in one of these parts.

The Spark UI shows that the program seems to perform slowly at the `reduceByKey` and `map` steps when determining `commonUsers`. The way I determined it is performing slowly is by comparing with the solution of fellow programmers. Furthermore I often get a GC overflow/Heap space exceeded error which would indicate some memory leak is happening in my code.

**EDIT**:
After some more investigation, I am quite sure the problem lies in the `reduceByKey(_++_)` step. I tried using `groupByKey` instead, but the program seems to fail on me and crash every time on that specific point.

Comment: First of all , please tell your configuration and how are you providing it and are you using it in cluster mode or client mode?

Comment: I am running Spark locally on Mac OSX with 8 GB of ram. Program is submitted using `spark-submit` with arguments `--driver-memory 5g` and 8 cores assigned by setting `spark.cores.max`.

Comment: What is slow? Compared to what? What stages are performing poorly? (You can see that on the spark UI page)

Comment: The Spark UI shows that the program seems to perform slowly at the `reduceByKey` and `map` steps when determining `commonUsers`. The way I determined it is performing slowly is by comparing with the solution of fellow programmers. Furthermore I often get a GC overhead/Heap space exceeded error which would indicate some memory leak is happening in my code.

Comment: How large is your input dataset?

Comment: The input set is a file of 1,15 GB

Comment: After some more investigation, I am quite sure the problem lies in the `reduceByKey(_++_)` step. I tried using `groupByKey` instead, but the program seems to fail on me and crash every time on that specific point.

Comment: There's something wrong with your algorithm. `pageAndUsers` contains only the set of pages visited by each user. Given that the user info is lost at that stage, I wonder how this is accomplishing the goal stated above "find all users at a certain distance of separation from a given user".

Comment: I thought that the aim would be that, given: Alice -> Page1, Bob -> Page1,  Bob -> Page2, Charly -> Page2 then:  Alice -1- Bob, Bob -1- Charly and Alice -2- Charly. Right?

Comment: `pageAndUser` contains the set of pages visited by each user, while `pageAndUsers` yields pairs of users (not pages) that are directly connected to each other. The aim that you give is correct, and I have verified it with a much smaller dataset.

Comment: @Laurens If `pageAndUser` is of type `RDD[User, Page]` (using concrete types instead of String to illustrate the point) then after the step `pageAndUser.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toArray).map(line => line._2)` we have `RDD[Array[Page]]`, which is what I found confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Performing a reduceByKey and using it to combine data which can grow to an indefinite size is dangerous. For example it looks as though you're linking users which share in some sense a page. But what if one of your users is linked to ALL other users. Then the array you're trying to construct in your reduceByKey will get incredibly large. This is the source of your memory and GC issues.

I expect if you look at the Spark UI when this stage is running you will see a few tasks hanging. These will be the ones where you have a single user linking to many users. (Perhaps all will be hanging in which case all your users are linking to all your users).

I'd save your data before your reduceByKey (the "pageAndUsers" RDD) and then query that data to see what's going on.

Perhaps if you have a 'small' amount of users in total you could use a set rather than an array since this will automatically 'distinct' your users in the value of the pair as it goes along so it may not grow too huge (depends on your data though).

However you need to look at your data to understand the issue. TO use the set logic I just mentioned here's some example (not exactly fast) code:

```
val pageAndUsers = pageAndUser.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toSet)
    .map(line => line._2)
val commonUsers = pageAndUsers.flatMap(users => users.map(user => (user, users)))
    .reduceByKey(_ ++ _).cache()
```

Comment: As you suggested I tried saving the `pageAndUsers` RDD and performing `count`. The Spark GUI states that its size is about 1 GB which looks fine to me. When I do the same with the step that includes the `reduceByKey` I see that the data size increases massively and spills data to disk. So the `reduceByKey` does indeed generate lots of data as you mentioned. What would be a good way to improve its performance?

Comment: Its not really a performance issue. If you left it for a few days it'd eventually fail due to spending all its time on GC. Dealing with a very large partitions is very finicky, depends on whaty exactly you want out and what your data looks like. For now I'd query your data to find out the 'bad' pages and then filter them out in your filter. The odds are you probably don't want every user linked to every user anyway cause of of a couple of pages.